# Virtual Serial Port Crash On Receive Using Android Emulator ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu, virtual-serial-port

Did someone encountered a problem with the virtual serial port.
I am using Virtual Serial Port Driver v9.0, of Eltima.

I succeed to send some string from the shell to other pc terminal application such as Hercules.
When I send string back to the android shell, using the following command:

```
generic_x86_64:/ # cat < /dev/ttyS1

or

generic_x86_64:/ # cat /dev/ttyS1
```

I get the following error:
***ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'.***

```
My Android Studio Version:
Android Studio 4.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 2014M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false, cidr.max.intellisense.file.length=1400000
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.thoughtworks.gauge, com.intellij.lang.jsgraphql, org.intellij.plugins.markdown, name.kropp.intellij.makefile, BashSupport, org.siprop.android.opencl.OpenCLCLGenerator, PythonCore, aws.toolkit
```

```
Using the Following AVD:
CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86_64)
Target: default [Default Android System Image] (API level 28)
Skin: 1024x600
SD Card: 512 MB
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: 7in WSVGA (Tablet)
hw.lcd.width: 1024
hw.initialOrientation: landscape
image.androidVersion.api: 28
tag.id: default
hw.mainKeys: no
hw.camera.front: emulated
avd.ini.displayname: DOV
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.ramSize: 2048
PlayStore.enabled: false
fastboot.forceColdBoot: yes
hw.cpu.ncore: 2
hw.keyboard: no
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
hw.dPad: no
hw.lcd.height: 600
vm.heapSize: 48
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Generic
hw.gps: yes
skin.path.backup: _no_skin
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-28\default\x86_64\
showDeviceFrame: no
hw.camera.back: None
hw.lcd.density: 160
hw.arc: false
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
fastboot.forceFastBoot: no
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Default Android System Image
runtime.network.latency: none
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Comment: Bug has been reported her: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172349340